# "d3.selectAll().style()" does not apply the styles to the selected elements, but within this selection with "d3.select(this).style()" if it works

Tags: javascript, d3.js

With this css rule, I manage to put opacity to an element within a svg.

[image]

```
#graph4 > svg  g.c3-chart-bar.c3-target.c3-target-data3{
    opacity: 0.3 !important;
}
```

but in my script with this code opacity does not apply.

```
setTimeout(()=>{
  d3.selectAll("#graph4 > svg g.c3-chart-bar.c3-target.c3-target-data3").style("opaciy",0.3) //not works
},2000)
```

But I do this if it applies. why?

```
setTimeout(()=>{
  d3.selectAll("#graph4 > svg g.c3-chart-bar.c3-target.c3-target-data3").style("opaciy",function(){
    d3.select(this).style("opacity",0.3); //it works
    return "";
  });
},2000)
```

Comment: You should really consider deleting your question altogether as it was a simple, trivial typo with nothing to learn from for the rest of us. This will help eliminating clutter on the site. You might need to unaccept the answer, though, before being able to delete the question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like opacity is misspelled in a couple of places (opaciy).